# NSNumberFormatter-Decimal Style-To format unlimited characters

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

The below code is used for my requirement for unlimited characters to be formatted to decimal style.But it works for upto 18 digits only,

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];    

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

long long num =  [textField.text longLongValue];

NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:num]];

textField.text = formattedOutput;

[formatter release];
```

What to do?

Thanks in Advance 
Bhaskar

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem in the formatted string, the problem may be in the textField.

Example:

```
long long maxLongLong = 0x7fffffffffffffff;
NSLog(@"maxLongLong: %llu", maxLongLong);

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];    
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:maxLongLong]];
NSLog(@"formattedOutput: %@", formattedOutput);
```

NSLog output:

```
maxLongLong: 9223372036854775807
formattedOutput: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

However, `NSNumberFormatter` does not seem to work with `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Thanks for your code, its helps me more.
But i have an issue,i used your code in 'textfieldshouldEndEditing', first time its work normally but when we going back to the textfield , and coming out of it , then the value changes. 

For example i entered value for first time is 123456789123456789
 and got this output  123,456,789,123,456,789
 and now when we re-enter and exit from the textfield with or without editing, i am getting the value is 123.

and other issue is,  its formatting upto 18 characters only 
If entered more than 18 we getting other answer i.e., 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: Check the textField code, are you getting the correct string back? 9223372036854775807 is the maximum signed integer for long long, for larger numbers you will either have to use floating point, tool your own number handling or fine a numeric package that handles larger integers.